# Suggestions for statistical model/approach to “Pattern recognition for non-uniform time data”

Tags: sas, statistics, timestamp, time-series, pattern-recognition

I have a dataset from which I would like to detect recurring patterns (i.e: daily, weekly, monthly). The dataset only contains a time stamp (datetime), and the spacing is non-uniform.

The observations in the data reflect the exact time when this one person passes my window. He does this several times a day (on a single day he walks by my window approx 10-30 times), and I am trying to see, if there is any pattern (there might also be some seasonality, sudden changes in previous behavior and other interesting stuff going on).

Does anyone have a suggestion for a statistical model/approach that might be helpful in figuring out if there is any pattern in this behavior? Hopefully, I’ll be able to predict when he will pass my window again ;)
How would you approach this?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Uh...is someone stalking you? You may have bigger issues! I would start by creating a plot, x axis is day and y axis is time of day. You can also consider a radar type chart if that helps.

Comment: It might be a stalker, or just a person who really likes the street on which I’m living :) And thank you, @Reeza. I’ll try the plot as well as a radar chart.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should be useful.

Comment: So sorry @jsb. Not really helpful, but thanks anyway. I have tried my best to formulate the question as simple as possible. Of course this is just an example and is not the real data that I’m working with.

Comment: This question is more about statistics than programming. You may get a better response on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, @user667489. I did not know about that page. I’ll definitely try there :)